# Show additional columns in ag grid pivot mode

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Working with AG Grid, I need to display some children columns with the pivot mode. E.g.: I would like to add the `countryCode` as the children of the `country`, but when I add like the normal ag-grid table, it doesn't show the child column and the `country`.
[image]

This is the sample code, you can also find that in ag-grid document
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/pivoting/

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef, ColGroupDef, GridReadyEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { IOlympicData } from './interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
      [pivotMode]="true"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  </div> `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: (ColDef | ColGroupDef)[] = [
    { field: 'country', rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup: true, children: [ { field: 'countryCode' }] },
    { field: 'sport', pivot: true },
    { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 150,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
  };
  public autoGroupColumnDef: ColDef = {
    minWidth: 250,
  };
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    this.http
      .get<IOlympicData[]>(
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => (this.rowData = data));
  }
}
```